# Spring Boot Jetty server not works over https (SSL)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, https, jetty

I have a Spring Boot application which runs on a remote server. When I build it to work over HTTP everything works fine. But when I am trying to setup SSL the application not work. It doesn't throw errors or anything. But I can't access any page in the browser (I have tried https://www.example.com, https://www.example.com:8443, https://example.com etc).

- I have built keystore.jks on remote server machine from certificate.crt (which I have bought for my domain on ssl).
- I have the following application.properties:

  server.port=8443

  server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks

  server.ssl.key-store-password=PASSWORD

  server.ssl.key-password=PASSWORD

I have tried different configurations but no results. The same story happens when I trying to run it on my local machine (I thought it is because of I am going to localhost when the certificate is for example.com but maybe it is the same problem).

Here is the server output:

> INFO 11041 --- [           main] o.e.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory     : x509=X509@2a492f2a(jetty,h=[www.example.com, example.com],w=[]) for >SslContextFactory@3277e499(jar:file:/root/application.jar!/BOOT->INF/classes!/keystore.jks,null)
>
> 2018-05-13 13:21:56.175  INFO 11041 --- [           main] >o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector       : Started >ServerConnector@7ac2e39b{SSL,[ssl, http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8443}
>
> 2018-05-13 13:21:56.176  INFO 11041 --- [           main] >.s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer : Jetty started on port(s) 8443 (ssl, http/1.1)
>
> 2018-05-13 13:21:56.179  INFO 11041 --- [           main] >c.b.product.BootApplication      : Started BootApplication in 4.786 seconds (JVM running for 5.151)

So everything seems to be fine but it doesn't work.

Comment: UPD: It work well with self-signet certificate. So it seems to be a certificate problem. How can I check what exactly is wrong with certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was just wrong generated keystore.jks.